# How to display email id of facebook user friend in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to create an iOS application which has Facebook integration i have completed this things but i want to get my all friend email id in table view so please tell me how can i achieve it .

I have used facebook Graph API

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0):

Email permission gives access to your email only.

Email is a protected property and must be specifically asked for and granted.

[Link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/email-permissions/)